# Cardinality of $m\Bbb Z_n = \{\overline {ma} : a \in \Bbb Z_n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $m,n \in \Bbb Z^+$ such that m divides n. I'm trying to find the cardinality of $m\Bbb Z_n = \{\overline {ma} : a \in \Bbb Z_n\}$. So, I think #$(m\Bbb Z_n)= \frac n m = k$. I tried to prove by it induction on $k$. Obviously it holds for $k=1$ but then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use induction. You only need to note that $\overline{km}=0$ in $\Bbb Z_n$.